# Complex error when trying to run footBayes/ stan on R

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

```
## Get the footbayes package from github
#library(devtools)
#install_github("LeoEgidi/footBayes")
library(footBayes)

## Other libraries 

## Pacakge where Leonardo gets his data for Italian Serie A 2000-2001
#install.packages("engsoccerdata")
library(engsoccerdata)
#data(package="engsoccerdata")    # lists datasets currently available
engsoccerdata::italy

## Save data from the Italian league
italy_data <- as.data.frame(italy)
summary(italy_data)

## This is a comprehensive dataset - includes data from seasons from year 1929 to year 2015

## Copying Leonardo's code
italy_2000 <- subset(italy[, c(2,3,4,6,7)], ## this is to filer for only some columns of interest, and also to filter for season 2000
                     Season =="2000")


###########################

## Run the MCMC 

n_iterations <- 200 ## number of MCMC interations -- generally the more the better convergence
fit1_stan <- stan_foot(italy_2000, 
                       model = "biv_pois", 
                       chains = 4,
                       iter = n_iterations)
```

I end up getting a really long error:

> make cmd is   make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f
> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX14)
> $(CXX14STD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)'
> SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)'
> SHLIB="file446c2d10260.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN= OBJECTS="file446c2d10260.o"
>
> make would use if test "zfile446c2d10260.o" != "z"; then \   if test
> -e "file446c2d10260-win.def"; then 
> echo g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file446c2d10260.dll file446c2d10260-win.def file446c2d10260.o
> -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/bin/x64" -lR ; 
> g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file446c2d10260.dll file446c2d10260-win.def file446c2d10260.o
> -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/bin/x64" -lR ; \   else 
> echo EXPORTS > tmp.def; 
> nm file446c2d10260.o | sed -n 's/^.* [BCDRT] / /p' | sed -e '/[.]refptr[.]/d' -e '/[.]weak[.]/d' | sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/"&"/g'  >>
> tmp.def; 
> echo g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file446c2d10260.dll tmp.def file446c2d10260.o
> -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/bin/x64" -lR ; 
> g++  -shared -s -static-libgcc -o file446c2d10260.dll tmp.def file446c2d10260.o
> -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64" -L"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib"  -L"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/bin/x64" -lR ; 
> rm -f tmp.def; \   fi \ fi Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :    C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe:
> file446c2d10260.o:file446c2d10260.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev[_ZN3tbb8internal26task_scheduler_observer_v3D0Ev]+0x1d):
> undefined reference to
> `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: file446c2d10260.o:file446c2d10260.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x1d): undefined reference to` tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe:
> file446c2d10260.o:file446c2d10260.cpp:(.text$_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface623task_scheduler_observerD1Ev]+0x3a): undefined reference to
> `tbb::internal::task_scheduler_observer_v3::observe(bool)'C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe:
> file446c2d10260.o:file446c2d10260.cpp:(.text$*ZN3tbb10interface623task*
> Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection

I am very new to this, appreciate any help I can get. To use this particular package (footBayes) I also had to install Rtools 4.2 from the web, which is not the latest version.